# How to increase size of software RAID0 Arrays?

Tags: linux, rhel, devices, raid, mdadm

My `Raid0` array consists of two `partition components`.

```
[root@rhel-85 ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Jan  9 17:25:26 2022
        Raid Level : raid0
        Array Size : 3141632 (3.00 GiB 3.22 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sun Jan  9 17:25:26 2022
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : original
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : none

              Name : rhel-85:0  (local to host rhel-85)
              UUID : bf76445f:08e4dab7:3861a780:76912221
            Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        8        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n2p1
       1     259        5        1      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p5
[root@rhel-85 ~]#
```

I have taken backup of all data from the raid0 array. Now, I want to add `/dev/nvme0n2p5` partition component to the `Raid0` array

After taking the backup, I am running the following commands:

```
[root@rhel-85 ~]# umount /dev/md0
umount: /dev/md0: not mounted.

[root@rhel-85 ~]# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] 
md0 : active raid0 nvme0n2p1[0] nvme0n1p5[1]
      3141632 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

[root@rhel-85 ~]# mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/nvme0n2p5
mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/nvme0n2p5 as 2: Invalid argument
```

Please let me know what commands to add partition `/dev/nvme0n2p5` to the `Raid0` array?

Comment: So you want to remove `/dev/nvme0n2p1` and add `/dev/nvme0n2p5` instead? Can you show your entire storage with `lsblk`? The device being busy doesn't necessary means it is mounted, if you have something stacked on top of the array (like LVM) you need to stop/deactivate these first.

Comment: RAID0 doesn't have any redundancy, so can't remove component devices without it breaking. Which do you want to do, add `nvme0n2p5` as a third component, or replace `nvme0n2p1` with it?

Comment: I want to add `nvme0n2p5` the third component. Do I need to format the `/dev/md0` again? What are the steps to break `raid0`?

Comment: First of all, you say in the commend that you want to add a third disk, but in the question itself you're trying to remove a disk. So do you have problems with adding a disk to the raid, or removing a disk? Second, have you tried [googling](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=linux+mdadm+raid0+add+disk)?

Comment: My understanding is that in order add 3rd disk, I firstly need to remove the existing disks. That is why I was trying to remove the disks one by one. I am having issue adding 3rd disk and need steps for it. I tried to google but couldn't find anything concrete. However, the link given by you is helpful.

Comment: I have updated my question. The command `mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/nvme0n2p5` is not working